# Инициализация начального состояния в React-Redux-приложении

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Делаю приложение на React JS. Непонятная проблема с инициализацией начального состояния. В консоли при выполнении команды npm start выдается такое сообщение

```
 bundle.js:23330 Unexpected keys "date", "currencies" found 
 inpreloadedState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of 
 the known reducer keys instead: "currencyReducer". Unexpected keys will be  
  ignored.
```

actions.js:

```
   export const refreshDate = (date, currencies)  => ({
     type: 'REFRESH_DATE', date, currencies
 });
```

reducer.js:

```
 export const currencyReducer = (state, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
      case 'REFRESH_DATE':
      let new_state = Object.assign({}, { date : action.date, currencies :       action.currencies} );
      console.log(new_state);
      return new_state;
       default:
         return state || { date : new Date(), currencies : [] };
       }
     };
```

фрагмент app.js:

```
  const iniState = { date : new Date, currencies : [] };  
  export const store = createStore(combineReducers(reducers), iniState,  
    applyMiddleware(refreshDate));
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А как вы подключаете `reducers` в *app.js*?

Comment: Вот так: import * as reducers from './reducers';

Comment: Ок, а что тогда из себя представляет _./reducers_?

Comment: export const currencyReducer = (state, action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
           case 'REFRESH_DATE':
              let new_state = Object.assign({}, { date : action.date,   currencies : action.currencies} );
             console.log(new_state);
             return new_state;
         default:
           return state || { date : new Date(), currencies : [] };
         }
     };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аргумент *preloadedState* функции *createStore* (`iniState`) должен представлять из себя будущий стейт, который у Вас имеет такую структуру:

```
{
    currencyReducer: {
        date: new Date(), 
        currencies: []
    }
}
```

А Вы пытаетесь подсунуть ему

```
{ date : new Date(), currencies : [] }
```

На что явно указывает эта запись:

> Unexpected keys **"date", "currencies"** found 
>    in **preloadedState argument** passed to **createStore**